# How can i display a sprite as a splash for some 5 seconds?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

How can i display a fruit sprite when some conditions are satisfied,something like 'fruit icon x 5',it must fade of after some 5 seconds.

Comment: You need a splash screen for iPhone?

Comment: no i need a splash sprite,during gameplay,something like a 'level up' splash display in mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand right, you can do it with actions.

```
id delay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration: delayDuration];
id fadeOut = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration: fadeOutDuration];
id sequence = [CCSequence actionOne: delay two: fadeOut];
[fruitSprite runAction: sequence];
```

Comment: And what if i want to display a label(fruit count) along with the fruit sprite ??

Comment: if you want label to fade/move with your sprite, you can create equal actions for both nodes, or, for example, just add your label as a child to sprite. Then all actions you will run for sprite will be automatically applied to it's children. Or if you have a couple of sprites with labels, you can create class that will contain both sprite and label and run all of your actions on this class.

Comment: The class thing will work,but the addchild method aint working.

Comment: create CCNode subclass, make it to be conformed CCRGBAProtovol, create array of fadable children and translate opacity to them in setOpacity: method

Answer (score 1):

in cocos2dx 3.6

```
Sprite Name->runAction(Sequence::create(MoveTo::create(1.5,Vec2(523,450)),
    DelayTime::create(1.0),ScaleTo::create(0.1, 1.5),ScaleTo::create(0.1, 1), NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create seperate view controller then display it as modal view with timer. After NSTimer reaches end do dismissModalViewControllerAnimated() method to come back to first view.
It's the simplest way to achieve your goal in pure Obj. C.

Comment: his question is about cocos2d methods, but not UIKit